# How to know the IP of my router

Tags: router

I got a kextech wireless n wifi router repeater access

https://www.tokopedia.com/tokoaon/kextech-wireless-n-wifi-router-repeater-dual-lan-port-300mbps

I usually access that router at IP 192.168.10.253

Now I can't access that anymore at that IP.

If I tracert to the main router this is what I got

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     6 ms    10 ms    10 ms  192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1]

Trace complete.

C:\Users\jim2>
```

It used to work fine. 
Then the wireless part seemed broken. After that I tried set things up again,  Restarted the router. And all the router is does is extending my LAN cable.

I got to the main router and I saw this ARP table there:

```
MAC Address     IP Address  Remaining Lease Time    Host Name   Port
88:63:df:59:97:f8   192.168.1.5 83678       SSID1
40:4d:7f:b9:6b:77   192.168.1.6 69532       SSID1
9c:b7:0d:d9:26:dc   192.168.1.3 31850       SSID1
74:23:44:eb:4a:98   192.168.1.4 69525       SSID1
00:e2:66:59:dc:39   192.168.1.2 73125       LAN1
90:4c:e5:36:a7:58   192.168.1.9 83324       SSID1
10:78:d2:3b:5d:b6   192.168.1.10    85805       LAN1
b0:e2:35:d0:a0:5a   192.168.1.8 85738       SSID1
64:cc:2e:0a:53:47   192.168.1.7 85824       LAN1
```

It seems that my new router has IP of 192.168.1.2

However, accessing 192.168.1.2 doesn't show anything either.
[image]

I downloaded the manual here

http://www.siig.com/media/files/manuals/0012/04-0867a.pdf

It seems, that for whatever reason, the Kextech repeater can only be accessed at address 192.168.253.10 and can only be accessed by a computer whose ip is 192.168.10.x

So I followed the instruction in the manual and change my computer IP to 192.168.10.1

[image]

and I still cannot access the router.

Comment: I’m not quite sure how all the devices are (supposed to be) connected. Please describe (or draw a picture!) of how the devices in your network (your PC, repeater thingy, actual router) are connected to each other.

Comment: Being able to only access your router configuration page by using "192.168.253.10" to access it is normal.  You don't want your router to be accessed by anyone outside of your network.

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to change in DHCP configuration of the LAN interface of the wifi repeater. If you are connected to Wifi from repeater, Check your IP settings on the machine using `ipconfig /all` I am quite sure you will be having IP from subnet 192.168.1.0/24.

> Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] over a maximum of 30 hops:
>
> 1     6 ms    10 ms    10 ms  192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1]

If this traceroute is from the machine connected to the wifi repeater, via wifi?. Then the device at 192.168.1.1 you are thinking is the main router, is actually not the main router. It is the wifi repeater and your gateway has been indeed changed from 192.168.10.253 to 192.168.1.1. And you should get your portal on 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Please mark the answer as answered or helpful, If it helped in getting you the answer! :)